# How to back up a network volume to my Time Capsule?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, backup, time-machine, airport, time-capsule

I have a Time Capsule that I'm using for my backups.

I have a network volume (coincidentally on the same time capsule) that I'd like to back up as well.

How can I tell Time Machine to back up network volumes in addition to my main laptop hard drive?

PS: yes, I know this setup isn't ideal.  It'll incur 2x network overhead when backing up the network volume, plus my data won't be safe in the event of a drive failure since both copies will be on the same disk.  However, it will give me some small amount of safety in the event I accidentally delete files on the network volume, among other things.

Comment: Hi mike, I dont think you able to back up two different volumes with time machine, unless you can have serpentine time machine instances running in different locations - not sure though.  I know their is not option, as Im sure you've discovered, but I do not know of any hacks either.

Answer (score 2):

Mike,

> I have a network volume (coincidentally on the same time capsule) that I'd like to back up as well.
>
> How can I tell Time Machine to back up network volumes in addition to my main laptop hard drive?

You can't.  Time Machine is only designed to backup local volumes, and not Network drives.

The only way this would work is if you copied the data locally, and then ran a Time Machine Backup...  You could then delete the local data, and that would *NOT* remove it from the Time Machine backup.